# Terminal continues to open chrome, even though firefox is default browser

Tags: mac, browser, iterm2

I recently updated my default browser from Chrome to Firefox. I am working on a MacBook Pro.

If I run a local app(ex: localhost:8000), such as a react app, iTerm2 will open Chrome, instead of Firefox. Oddly, if I push to my git branch and click the PR link in iTerm it will open whatever browser that was last used. Running any local app will default to open in Chrome. How can I update my iTerm2 to use Firefox to open local applications?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fixed, please let me know if my updated description is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well and it might depend on how you're running your app. Sometimes the default browsers for the build tools you have are different than your system ones.

For example in vite I needed to set the BROWSER variable in my terminal to firefox to stop it from opening my apps in chrome.

```
export BROWSER=firefox
npm run dev #which runs vite dev and opens the app in firefox
```

For webpack you can change this using webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    open: 'Google Chrome'
  }
};
```

So it will depend on how your application is being ran and the settings with that tool.